# How to fix - Unused declaration of function 'product'

Tags: c

I am trying to run a program which I copied from a source code. It keeps showing the warning

```
"Unused declaration of function   'product'" for this line: int product(int x, int y);
```

And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There must be a prototype declaration of that function, that was not use, meaning, the function itself was not defined. Just find the line `int product(int x, int y);` and comment it. The warning should go.

Comment: that must be the function prototype. You are surely not using the 'product'  function anywhere. So, delete (or better, comment to be safe) the declaration and definition (if any) of 'product' function...and get going :)

Answer (score 2):

There must be a prototype declaration of that function, that was not used, meaning, the function itself was not defined.

Just find the line `int product(int x, int y);` and comment it. By adding 2 `//`

```
//int product(int x, int y);
```

The warning would go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a very beginner. How should I comment it?

Comment: Thanks Haris. It works now. Your comment was very helpful.